# Compare two arrays and update with the new values by keeping the existing objects using javascript-Not working for delete operation of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is a follow up question for [Compare two arrays and update with the new values by keeping the existing objects using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36128011/compare-two-arrays-and-update-with-the-new-values-by-keeping-the-existing-object) which was ansewered by @Siderite Zackwehdex

Please check this  [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/4z8QB1qJacHDg6FM3EUg?p=preview) I'm getting the deleted Object in the changedArray1.Is there any option to fix this.Its working fine for other changes like add,update but not for delete.

One feature that I tried to implement is to add an additional object ie., `"removedIds":[23] ,` that holds the deleted id's as an array in each level of objects and identifying them in the evaluation process.. but didn't find the right soultion

Example data:

```
var parentArray1=[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test",
        "context": [
            {
                "operationalContextId": 1.1,
                "valueChainEntityDetails": [
                    {
                        "valuChainEntityId": 3,
                        "name": "test",
                        "context": [
                            {
                                "id": 3.1,
                                "name": "test 3.1",
                                "activityDetails": [
                                    {
                                        "activityId": 22,
                                        "name": "test 3.1"
                                    },
                                     {                   //trying to remove activity id 23
                                        "activityId": 23,
                                        "name": "changed test 23"
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]



var changedArray1=[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "test2",
        "context": [
            {
                "operationalContextId": 1.1,
                "valueChainEntityDetails": [
                    {
                        "valuChainEntityId": 3,
                        "name": "changed test3",
                        "context": [
                            {
                                "id": 3.1,
                                "name": "test 3.1",
                                 "removedIds":[23] ,
                                "activityDetails": [  //activity id 23 is removed in this JSON but reflecting in parentArray1
                                    {
                                        "activityId": 22,
                                        "name": "changed test 3.1"
                                    }

                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Where's the JS?

Comment: Its in plunker.I tried to add removedId's functioality.Its breaking existing features

Comment: Please put the relevant JS (suitable reduced to the portion required to demonstrate the problem) directly into the question.